# How to prove the coupling version of the Donsker's Invariance Principle?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

> Donsker's invariance principle:
> Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be i.i.d. real-valued random variables with mean 0 and variance 1. We define $S_0=0$ and $S_n= X_1+ ... + X_n$ for $n \geq 1$. To get a process in continuous time, we interpolate linearly and define for all $t \geq 0$
> $$
> S_t = S_{[t]}+ (t-[t])(S_{[t]+1}- S_{[t]}).
> $$
> Then we define for all $t \in [0,1]$
> $$
> S^*_n(t)= \frac{S_{nt}}{\sqrt{n}}.
> $$
> Let $C[0,1]$ be the space of real-valued continuous function defined on $[0,1]$ and endow space with the supremumnorm. Then $(S^*_n(t))_{0 \leq t \leq 1}$ can be seen as a random variable taking values in $C[0,1]$. Now let $\mu_n$ be its law on that space of continuous functions and let $\mu$ be the law of Brownian motion on $C[0,1]$. Then the following holds:

> **Theorem (Donsker):** The probability measure $\mu_n$ converges weakly to $\mu$, i.e. for every $F: C([0,1]) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ bounded and continuous,
> $$
> \int F d\mu_n \rightarrow \int F d\mu
> $$
> as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

But for a two-dimensional case, the 'coupling version' is as following.

$\textbf{'coupling version'}$: Fix a square $S$ of size $s$. Fix $x\in nS$. Let $X$ be a random walk starting from $x$ until it exits the square $nS$ and let $B$ be a Brownian motion until it exits $nS$. For $\forall \epsilon>0$, then there exists $N>0$ such that $n\ge N$, one can couple $X$ and $B$ so that
$$d(X,B)\le \epsilon n.$$

My questions:
(1) Can we extended the classical Donsker's to the two-dimensional case?

(2) Is there any reference for the proof of the 'coupling version'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this can be done in any dimension but the two dimensional case is especially simple. Rotating a simple RW in two dimensions by 45 degrees yields a random walk where the $x$ and $y$ coordinates are independent. Couple each coordinate to a BM using Skorokhod embedding to obtain the desired coupling.